# Clash amsthm and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, miktex, texworks, amsthm

The program below shows a problem with `hyperref` and `amsthm`. Not really a problem for me, since I don't use `amsthm` anyway so I just threw it out, but still it took me quite some time to figure it out.
At the office I didn't have this problem, by the way.
I use TeXworks and pdfLaTeX, and updated all packages involved to the latest versions.
Hope this is enough info to get the problem fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

This leads to the error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)

....  irrelevant output deleted   ....

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
(C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...}}[]}\fi \@tempa }\fi \dth@everypar 
                                                  ={\@minipagefalse \global ...
l.7379 }{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your MWE compiled just fine for me.  I am using TeXLive 2013 so maybe this is a MikTex problem not a package problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a package clash that doesn't exist or is not reproducible in its present form.

Comment: Just found out I had a very old version of the file amsthm.sty in the directory I was working in. I got rid of it and now everything works fine again. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `\listfiles` at the beginning and compare the versions. I do not get any errors.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
    test.out
    test.out
 ***********
```

Also check the paths of the packages. The paths before your error message look like a mixup of a system and user installation of MiKTeX.